# Maximum number of points between two parallel lines

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, lines, points

I am given N+2 points with integer coordinates. 2 of them are base-points. Two parallel lines need to be drawn through the given base-points. What is the maximum number of points situated between the two parallel lines? Sorry for my english and thanks in advance!

In the following picture the RED dots are the base-points, the BLACK ones are the normal points. The yellow area is where the maximum number of black points need to be. If one of the black points is ON one of the lines, it is considered that this point IS between the lines.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awhg6.png

I found a solution in time complexity O(N*N) but this is too slow.

Comment: Do you mean "maximum number of points on a line connecting those two lines"? If so, does it have to be perpendicular to them or not? If perpendicular, then it'll be the same as the distance between the lines. Otherwise, you can figure the distances between the corners, and choose the longest. If you're not talking about points on a line, then we probably need even more explanation.

Comment: Is the C++ question to follow?

Comment: To downwoters: this is a legitimate question. Perhaps mistagged and not showing signs of own effort, but neither offtopic nor "not a real question".

Comment: I have removed the "c++" tag and added the "algorithm" tag. Also, if this is a homework, it needs to be tagged as such.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine your two lines pass through both base points. The width of the strip between the lines is 0 and there are no points inside (or there are some points, depending on your definition of "inside").

Now imagine the two lines slowly rotate counterclockwise, while staying parallel. After finishing half a turn, they are in the same position as before. As the lines rotate, they go through your points, which thereby enter and leave the strip between the lines.

Assuming the lines make some fixed number of rotations per unit of time, calculate, for each point, the time of it entering the strip between the lines, and the time of it leaving the strip. (These times are basically angles). Sort both kind of events together. Now go through the events, counting +1 for each entry event and -1 for each exit event. For the events that happen at the same exact time, do the -1 first or +1 first, again depending on your definition of "inside". Keep track of the maximum count.